# real world application of clojure STM

Tags: clojure, stm

As I understand clojure STM can be used for transacting values across refs.

I understand this property is useful in datastores, where 2 or more locations have to be mutated in a single transaction - atomicity.

However in what cases will this be useful in software applications ? I could just store all my state in one map and use an clojure.core/atom if I want shared mutable state.

In what types of applications / scenarios will usage of refs make sense over atoms or other state primitives in clojure.

Comment: I think the question is too general. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#Conceptual_advantages_and_disadvantages

Answer (score 2):

Using an atom is indeed what's suggested in the [Elements of Clojure](https://leanpub.com/elementsofclojure/read_full) book by Zach Tellman (chapter 2 - *If you have mutable state, use an atom*).
They say that until ~60% utilization of the stateful container, an atom is probably a better choice.
The advice is summarized at the end of the section as:

- If you have mutable state, make sure it belongs inside your process.
- If it does, try to represent it as a single atom.
- If that causes performance issues, try spreading the work across more processes.
- If that isn’t possible, see if the atom can be split into smaller atoms that don’t require shared consistency.
- Finally, if that doesn’t help, you should start looking into Clojure’s STM primitives.